# Incorrect font rendering in Qt (Symbian)

Tags: qt, symbian, nokia, truetype

I've been trying to get custom font rendering working in a Symbian Qt app (4.6) for some time. For most fonts and most glyphs, it all works just fine using a method similar to [this](http://juhaturunen.com/blog/2010/12/using-custom-fonts-on-qtsymbian/).

However, for the majority of fonts many glyphs are rendered incorrectly - essentially, the wrong glyph is rendered. I've tried a Symbian C++ app using the same loading method, and that **does** render correctly. So, this does seem like a Qt bug, and in fact all the gory details are [here](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-17506).

Can anyone suggest a workaround to get full TTF font rendering working on Symbian^3 devices in Qt 4.6?

Answer (score 1):

Although I have no experience with Symbian Qt Apps, I was working last year for several months in a dual environment Qt application (Win32 & Mac OS X) which has to do mainly with font rendering.

QFont rendering -in Win32/Mac OS X- in general runs smoothly, but if you have advanced font rendering requirements you may encounter several and severe problems:

a) It's not possible to find if a specific unicode character is really present in a specific font (i.e. it's not possible to totally disable the character-substitution mechanism - you can only provide substitution hints)

b) If you try to load some specific (bad?) TTF/OTF fonts for exclusive use of your application (i.e. to load not-installed fonts to use them in you application) the application crashes and the crash is inside the Qt Libraries code (it's trying to double-free some buffers).
This is a very rare bug to encounter: It was happened to me for just 5-10 fonts out of 90.000 fonts I tested, but it's still annoying if the main task of your application has to do with font-rendering.

My workaround was to use the [FreeType2 (open source)](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/index.html) library:

-> It never crashes (it just returns an error on bad fonts)

-> It's about 4-5 times faster than QFont rendering

FreeType2 is not a direct replacement for QFont and it for sure requires to spend some extra time to understand some basic (low-level) concepts before using it, but if you really need a fast and reliable library to render any TTF/OTF (+other) font into a gray or bw image, I highly recommend it as the ultimate choice.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate answer is that this is a QT bug, but happily it is fixed in QT 4.7.2. Now, just have to wait until the Ovi Store accepts Nokia QT 4.7.2 apps....